# Add postfix in java 8 way

Tags: java, java-8

I need a function which returns a set containing `{XXX11, XXX12, XXX13, XXX14, XXX21, ... , XXX43, XXX44}` where `XXX` is a integer argument of the function. What is a elegant way of **Java 8** style? I've done in case of prefix is one digit as following:

```
/**
 * I need to get {<base>11, <base>12, ..., <base>44} but can't...
 * @return {<base>1, <base>2, <base>3, <base>4}
 */
Set<Integer> addOnlyOnePrefix(int base){
  return IntStream.range(1, 4).map(prefix -> base*10 + prefix)
      .boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: It's probably _easiest_ to use the `toString` -> prepend -> `parseInt` method.

Comment: what's the series about? i.e. just after 14, 21?

Comment: @almasshaikh
It's 11,12,13,14,21,22,23,24,31,32,33,34,41,42,43,44. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `flatMap`.

First generate an `IntStream` of `1..4` and multiply it up by 10. Then `flatMap` another `IntStream` of `1..4` to give `11,12..21,22..`.

Multiply up the `base` by `100` and add it to the `IntStream`:

```
Set<Integer> addTwoPrefixes(final int base) {
    final int prefix = base * 100;
    return IntStream
            .rangeClosed(1, 4).map(i -> i * 10)
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).map(j -> i + j))
            .map(i -> base + i)
            .boxed()
            .collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

Note, I have collected to a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve order.

Comment: Personally, this is more helpful because I recently started to learn java 8 methods and `flatMap` seems useful in some other problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is probably to just generate 16 values:

```
Set<Integer> addOnlyTwoPrefixes(int base) {
  return IntStream.range(0, 16)
      .map(prefix ->
          base * 100 +             // Leading digits
          10 + 10 * (prefix / 4) + // Penultimate digit
          1 + (prefix % 4))        // Last digit
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

The 10+ and 1+ are to take account of `prefix / 4` and `prefix % 4` being in the range 0-3 rather than 1-4.

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion to write a method which adds n prefixes:

```
static IntStream addNPrefixes(int base, int n) {
    return n == 0 ? IntStream.of(base) : addNPrefixes(base, n - 1)
            .flatMap(b -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).map(prefix -> b * 10 + prefix));
}
```

Then the method you want would look like this:

```
static Set<Integer> addTwoPrefixesThenCollectToSet(int base) {
    return addNPrefixes(base, 2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

It's easy to change the first method to allow you pass in the prefix generating function also if you want to:

```
static IntStream addNPrefixes(int base, int n, Supplier<IntStream> prefixes) {
    return n == 0 ? IntStream.of(base) : addNPrefixes(base, n - 1, prefixes)
            .flatMap(b -> prefixes.get().map(prefix -> b * 10 + prefix));
}
```